# Django form names

Tags: python

This may seem a basic question but I can't find it anywhere.

If I have defined 3 separate forms within my forms.py file how are these provided in the template. I.e so I can only present 1 of these forms ?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you tried anything? Read [FAQ] first.

Comment: The documentation is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to import froms from forms.py in the view.py

like

```
from app.forms import my_form1, my_form2, my_form3
```

then, pass the required form to the HTML file like

```
render(request,
              'my_page.html',
              {'my_form': my_form1})
```